# PHP and MongoDB - strange sync problems

Tags: php, mongodb, asynchronous

My PHP has a strange behaviour:

```
$connection = new MongoClient('mongodb://<address>/db_name');
$db = $connection->db_name;

foreach ($area_array as $area) {
    $collection = $db->selectCollection($area . '_collection');

    $cursor = $collection->find(array('a' => $a));

    foreach ($cursor as $element) {
        res[$area][] = $element;
    }
}
```

**Yesterday situation:**

I knew for sure that collections were non-empty, in fact, if $area_array = ['cat'] or if $area_array = ['dog'], $res array was no empty in both of cases.

If $area_array had more than 2 elements this was what happened if I printed with echoes the number N of documents which $cursor was composed of:

- if $area_array = ['cat'], then N was 6;
- if $area_array = ['cat', 'dog'], then N was 0 (for 'cat') and 32 (for 'dog'), and $res had only 'dog' key!!

**Today situation:**

On this morning, everything works fine and I've seen both 'cat' and 'dog' keys in $res. The code remained perfectly the same w.r.t yesterday.

So, I there something asynchronous in mongodb calls from PHP? Maybe I can't put find() operations within a foreach loop? I cannot risk that strange behaviour!

Thanks